# In Boto 3, how do I define the IPs in a security group that will have access to the EC2 instance?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

In Boto 3, how do I define the IPs in a security group that will have access to the EC2 instance?

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
security_group = ec2.SecurityGroup('id')
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on documentation, I would say setting the IpRanges on the ip_permissions attribute of ec2.SecurityGroup.
http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.SecurityGroup.ip_permissions

There are some sample walkthrough examples here:
http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/security_groups.html